# Notation $2^T$ for the operator T of the Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I came across an unknown to me notation $2^T, 2^{-T}$ for a positive operator $T$ on a Hilbert space (more precisely, in $\mathbb{C}^n$).

What does this mean? I can't find it anywhere. Is it the image and the kernel?

Comment: Might $2^T$ just mean $\exp(\log(2) T) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{\log(2)^n}{n!} T^n$?

Comment: It would help if you gave the source. diracdeltafunk's suggestion is my first guess but it seems like a very bizarre thing to write down so I don't know.

Comment: It is not a standard notation for an operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no source. It was in the task next to the calculation of the norm and square root and finding the spectral decomposition, so you may be right. Thank you!

Comment: You have to read spectral theory to find out how to define functions of an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a positive (more generally, normal) operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$, there is a unique unital *-homomorphism (a linear map that preserves products and involutions) from $C(\sigma(T))$ to $B(H)$ that maps $\operatorname{id}$ to $T$, where $\operatorname{id}$ is the map $C(\sigma(T))\to \mathbb{C}, z\mapsto z$.

For a continuous function $f$ on the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$, $f(T)$ means the image of $f$ under the unique *-homomorphism.

For example, let $p(x)=x^2+2x+1$,  you can check $p(T)=T^2+2T+e$ where $e$ is the  identity of $B(H)$.

For $f(x)=2^x$, it can be approximated by polynomials $p_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(\ln 2)^n}{n!}x^n$ with respect to the uniform norm. $f(T)$ can be proved to be the limit of $p_N(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is a positive operator, it is a normal operator and we can consider the continuous functional calculus
$$C(\sigma(T)) \to  B(\mathbb{C}^n) \cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$$

Then $2^T$ is the operator obtained as the image of $\sigma(T)\ni x \mapsto 2^x$ under the above map.

In some sense, it is unnatural to consider the operator $2^T$ since $\sigma(T)$ is a finite space, but I think it suffices for your purposes.